# Values context in an included helm named template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

We have a helm chart that contains named templates to be used by other templates.

Originally, the helm chart containing the named templates has no "values.yaml" file, as all it has are "_function.tpl" files. But now, we would like to use a "values.yaml" file to define some values there instead of having to be passed by the caller like so after defining the dependency in the Chart.yaml.

`{{ include "libchart.velero" (list . .Values.velero )}}`

The named template then would have a definition, which converts those contexts passed as list to $root and "velero", so we can work comfortably with the caller passed context, like so:

```
{{- define "libchart.velero" -}}

{{- $root := index . 0 -}}
{{- $velero := index . 1 -}}
```

But question is, how could I define and consume the variables define in the "values.yaml" file present in the chart that contains the definition of the named template itself.

I've tried using things like `{{ $.Values.local }}` and `{{ .Values.local }}` to access "locally to the named template" defined variable, but no luck with those.

Answer (score 1):

With that construction, the top-level Helm object (which contains `Values`, `Release`, `Namespace`, *etc.* fields) is in the `$root` variable inside the template.

```
{{-/*
Call with a list of two items, the top-level Helm object and the
.Values.velero chart configuration.

Outputs something only if the `local` top-level value is set.
*/-}}
{{- define "libchart.velero" -}}
{{- $root := index . 0 -}}
{{- $velero := index . 1 -}}
{{- if $root.Values.local -}} {{-/* <-- like this */-}}
... {{ $velero }} ...
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: But that's what we already have right? i mean, it is the same code as the given in the question or am I not seeing something? In this case, the $root ends up being the scope provided by the caller, not the scope local to the chart where the .tpl file is defined.

Comment: `$root.Values...` will access things that you'd "normally" access with just `.Values`, but in this context the special variable `.` is the list template parameter.